# Member function that doesn't access member data, and encapsulation, coupling and cohesion

Tags: c++

A class having a member function which does not operate on the class's data members ( directly or indirectly), is it decreased encapsulation, tighter coupling, or lower cohesion? Why?
EDIT:

```
class Data  
{  
 private:  
  int value_;  

 public:  
  Data(int value) : value_(value) {}  

  int compute(int coef)  
  {  
    check(coef);  
    return coef * value_;  
  }  

  void check(int n)  
  {  
    if (n < 0 || n > 344) {  
      throw string("Invalid coef");  
    }  
  }  
};
```

The *check* member functionn verifies the validity of the parameter passed to the *compute* member function but it has nothing to do with the data members of *Data*

Comment: Is this a homework question? Do you have any thoughts on the matter? The *wording* makes it sound like a regurgitated question from an exam I once took. :p Please clarify your answer, show an example if you can.

Comment: I'm really not understanding this question, and at least part of the answer depends on whether the member function is `static` or not.  Could you post a small example, and be a little more verbose and specific with your questions?

Comment: why should it be any of your proposals ? What you describe looks like a normal static member method.

Comment: @kriss - it sounds more like a free function to me.  Even static members typically show some interest in the class in which they live.

Comment: @Steve Townsend: once your set them static member functions can't access to current instance members (this is just not available). They are still able to access to private members of others instances (maybe passed in) of the same type or static members. As far as I see, as static functions are more efficient, private members of the kind described by the OP should be described static (not so for protected or public members that can be inherited). Isn't it ?

Comment: @kriss - why are `static` member functions more efficient than free functions?

Comment: @Rup - that code won't compile unless your compiler is very old and assumes functions return `int`. Also it should be static, if for some reason you want to tightly couple this to the class rather than make it free.

Answer (score 6):

It is all three. You decrease encapsulation because the function *could* operate on the class's data members. You give it access to doing so even though it is unnecessary, thereby violating encapsulation. And for much the same reason, it results in lower cohesion and tighter coupling (the class becomes a grouping of functionality that seemingly has little reason to be grouped together.

In C++, free (non-member) functions are generally preferred in cases like this.

Comment: +1 Also, depending on whether you interpret _operate on_ as _modify_ or _read OR modify_, an argument could be made that the function should just be a `const` member function instead of a free member function.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say decreased encapsulation, because you give this class a member function which really doesn't belong there. Other two choices are more related to class vs other classes behaviour.

Anyway, I think it's highly debatable.

Answer (score 2):

If a member function does not operate on class's data members then either it should be `static` or it should not be a member of the class.

In a case like this, you should ask yourself: "Why is this function a member of the class?"  If it does something that only makes sense in the context of this particular class, then you make it `static` or at least `const`, and maybe even `private`.

On the other hand, if the function makes sense outside the context of the class, or, worse, if it is used outside the context of the class, then it reduces cohesion and increases coupling.  It reduces cohesion, because it does not logically belong to the class of which it is a member.  It increases coupling because while it may be used outside the context of its class, that class must nevertheless be known to the caller of the function.  In this case, the function should simply not be a member of the class.  Then there is no impact on cohesion or coupling.

I don't think it has any impact on encapsulation, though, since it does not expose any class members that are not already exposed.

Edit:

In your particular case `check()` should be `private` and either `static` or `const`.  `compute()` should be `const`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give an example

Let's say you build a class called Angle to haul around angles in different units.

Having a sin() function on the class would be worthless and just bloat the class interface whereas that function should simply be a separate free function.

Read this link on the Interface Principle: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill02.htm

Answer (score 0):

That depends. If the method needs access to anything private or protected then it needs to be a member or a friend of the class. That being said, you should always limit as much as possible the number of entities having access to the class' internals, because each entity can introduce bugs. Sometimes you can eliminate a private or protected member, and if that eliminates the original method's need for privileges then you can extract it outside the class.

If a method **belongs** in the class (something only you can judge) then it should be part of the class' **interface**. Remember though that being part of the class' interface doesn't imply being a member of the class. What reduces cohesion and encapsulation is not a method being a member but a method having more privileges than it needs. The same holds for increasing coupling and reduced information-hiding.

And yet that being said, there is an interesting debate about the tradeoffs between humane interfaces and minimal interfaces. This relates here, in that you might have a function that serves as a mere inline (alias) call for another function, in making an interface more intuitive. Such a function doesn't need any member access whatsoever but in C++ it's needed for an intuitive call as a member -- should you value intuitive interfaces and be part of the humane interface school of thought.

Comment: A member function can belong in a class but not an interface.  In that case, it should be `private`.

Comment: I dislike `protected`, don't know what you mean by member `friend`, and non-member `friend` does not belong in the class.

Comment: @David `protected` sometimes makes perfect sense. See the Template Method pattern. friends sometimes enhance encapsulation. See your IO streams library.

Answer (score 0):

In your revised question (with the code), the magic numbers in `check` should be `static const int` in the class (and `check` should be a `static` member).

Another option would be to construct the class with constraints as parameters, and private members.  Then `check` would not be static but again it would need to access class members.

You need to post an example that both exhibits good design and meets your stated limitations.  I doubt that can be done. To me, what you have described is a code smell as such a function should always be free.

Comment: as the check function is public, there is still a (remote) possibility that it is a non static member because some derived class should be able to use instance data to write a better check implementation.

Comment: @kriss - if OP had said "a *virtual* member function", I would agree.

Answer (score 0):

As all three expressions proposed "decreased encapsulation", "tighter coupling" and "lower cohesion" are a mesure of a program change (there is source before and a source after), it's not possible to answer your question.

Basically I'm saying **Tighter coupling than what ? Duh ?**

If you are asking about your proposed version and the use of an external function for check instead, I believe others have already answered.

About coupling and Cohesion you may want to read [that](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CouplingAndCohesion)